# i have models but ,by mistake i drop my db from server and again migrate those DB and table, so model getting error

Tags: mysql, laravel-7

i have database name and tables of my project, by mistake i change live servers ampps to xampp so i lost my DB and Table,so i have migrate the tables and face eerror is logs showing 'make:model' but i alreday have that models so what can i do with this stuff? is there any possible way to solve this problem?
[model not defind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72ZqA.png)

need solution of this problem i have model with migrated and table with database, so isthere any command to resolve the models in laravel

Comment: That's a typo error - nothing to do with your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just spelling mistake.

your command is like this :

```
php artisan make:model yourModelName
```